# How to request super su permission in android app

Tags: java, android, shell, root

I'm new to Android application programming and I have been trying to make a root app.  After all the coding, it doesn't work because it doesn't get the root access. I have read in other posts that I need to paste the following into the code to request `su`:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

However, I do not know where to paste it.  I tried in a few places, but I just get errors.

I have pasted this code in manifest:

```
'<'uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" '/>'
```

It shows superuser permission is needed while installing the app. But while running the app, it does nothing.

Any little help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  As a new user, it is a good idea to read the "help / site tour" page.  I hope you find the answer you are looking for!

Comment: is your device rooted?

Comment: Yes,my device is rooted other root apps work perfectly fine.